# How to atomatically apply migrations that comes from Yii2 extensions

Tags: yii2, yii2-extension

I have installed an extension for Yii2 [dektrium/yii2-user](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user) using composer using it's "require" section. This extension contains migrations for database. Is it possible to apply migrations from this extension using console syntax not like this:

```
php yii migrate --migrationPath=@dektrium/yii2-user/migrations
```

but run all migrations automatically by using a simple command like:

```
php yii migrate
```

Is it possible to tell composer where the concrete extension contains it's migrations?

Comment: yii migrate only take into consideration the migrations you have in your console/migrations folder

Comment: i found better solution that i had describe below. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make this process automated, you can use `scripts` property of `composer`. For more information you can see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md. In your case you can do your goal with something like this on `composer.json`:

```
{
 // Some codes are here
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php yii migrate --migrationPath=@dektrium/yii2-user/migrations"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php yii migrate --migrationPath=@dektrium/yii2-user/migrations"
        ]
    },
 // Some codes are here
}
```

I prefer to save all commands that must be run after install -or update- on a file (for example file named `commands`) in the root of project, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations
./yii migrate/up
./yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@app/modules/rules/migrations
./yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@app/modules/formsaz/migrations
./yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@app/modules/todo/migrations
./yii formsaz/rules/init
./yii husky/rules/init
```

and on `composer.json` file put its name:

```
{
 // Some codes are here
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "sh commands"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "sh commands"
        ]
    },
 // Some codes are here
}
```

So each time after `composer install` or `composer update`, all commands will be run (and it's useful on teamwork).

Answer (score 1):

I found only one good solution - Install yii2 extension https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-migrate-command

Now i can easily use command "php yii migrate" and don't worry that someone from my team doesn't apply required migrations.

Thanks others for help! If u find more appropriate solutions, please share =)

Answer (score 0):

[Yii2: Allow Migrate From Multiple Path](https://mdmunir.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/yii2-allow-migrate-from-multiple-path/)

Comment: I would upvote your answer if you wouldn't just have posted a link! This is now how SO works. Consider that the link gets broken at some time. Then your answer is useless.

Comment: @robsch when the link brakes, you can find it in the wayback machine - https://web.archive.org :)

Comment: [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): Provide context for links - Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.