# How run migrate commands by controller?

Tags: php, database, console, yii2, migrate

I want create an installation controller for my web app and for config db need run migration commands from controller.

For example when user visit

> localhost/backend/webapp/index.php?install/step1

by action step1 run migrate up and down command and do installation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call a console command in web application in Yii 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355483/how-can-i-call-a-console-command-in-web-application-in-yii-2-0)

Comment: Perhaps combining http://stackoverflow.com/a/35864018/1592247 and `exec` function of `php` could helps you. hum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks from @soju and @meysam you can use both solutions.

1. Use `exec`:

> Perhaps combining stackoverflow.com/a/35864018/1592247 and exec
>   function of php could helps (@meysam)

2. Use extensions:

> [How can I call a console command in web application in Yii 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355483/how-can-i-call-a-console-command-in-web-application-in-yii-2-0) (@soju)

Both way may help you.
be aware using exec may cause some security issues and disable in some servers.